# On the Diophantine equation $m^2 - p^k = 4z$, where $z \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p$ is a prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations, divisor-sum

The title says it all:

> Do there *always* exist $m, p, k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m^2 - p^k = 4z$, $z \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p$ is prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?

**MY ATTEMPT FOR $z=1$**

When $z = 1$, I get
$$m^2 - p^k = 4$$
$$p^k = m^2 - 4 = (m+2)(m-2)$$

Hence, we have the simultaneous equations $p^{k-x} = m+2$ and $p^x = m-2$ where $k \geq 2x + 1$.  Consequently, we have $p^{k-x} - p^x = 4$, which implies that 
$$p^x (p^{k-2x} - 1) = 4$$
where $k-2x$ is odd.  Since $(p-1) \mid (p^y - 1) \hspace{0.05in} \forall y \geq 1$, this last equation implies that $(p-1) \mid 4$.  Likewise, the congruence $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ implies that $4 \mid (p-1)$.  These two divisibility relations imply that $p-1=4$, or $p=5$.  Hence,
$$5^x (5^{k-2x} - 1) = 4.$$
Since $5$ does not divide $4$, $x=0$ and thus $5^k - 1 = 4$, which means that $k=1$.

Therefore, $p=5$, $k=1$, and $x=0$.  Consequently, $p^{k-x} = 5^{1-0} = 5 = m + 2$ and $p^x = 5^0 = 1 = m - 2$.  Either way, $m=3$.

**CONCLUSION**

> Thus, for the equation $m^2 - p^k = 4$, I get the solution $m=3$, $p=5$, and $k=1$.

**QUESTION**

> How does one treat the case for general $z \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}$?

For one, I cannot seem to wrap my head around $m^2 - p^k = 8$.

I could, of course, rewrite it as 
$$(m+3)(m-3) = m^2 - 9 = p^k - 1 = (p-1)\sigma(p^{k-1})$$
(where $\sigma$ is the classical sum-of-divisors function), but then I am no longer able to apply [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma).

*UPDATE TO QUESTION (January 20, 2020)*

The equation $m^2 - p^k = 4z$ (under the given constraints) does not have a solution when $z=4$.

Here is my additional question:

> When is the equation $m^2 - p^k = 4z$, where $z \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p$ is a prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, guaranteed to have a solution?

Comment: Consider $z=16$.  $m^2 - p^k = 64$, $m^2 - 64 = p^k$, $(m + 8)(m - 8) = p^k$.
$$p^{k-x} = m + 8$$
$$p^x     = m - 8$$

$$p^x (p^{k-2x} - 1) = 16$$

$$\gcd(p^x, 16) = 1 \implies p^{k-2x} - 1 = 16 \implies p^{k-2x} = 17 \implies p = 17 \land k - 2x = 1 \implies x = 0 \implies k = 1 \implies m = 9.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer.

Your idea works for $z=2^{2n}$.

**Claim** : For $z=2^{2n}$, if $2^{n+2}+1$ is prime, then $(m,p,k)=(2^{n+1}+1,2^{n+2}+1,1)$. If $2^{n+2}+1$ is not prime, then there is no solution.

*Proof* :

For $z=2^{2n}$, we have

$$m^2 - p^k = 2^{2n+2}\iff p^k=(m-2^{n+1})(m+2^{n+1})$$
So, there is a non-negative integer $a$ such that
$$m+2^{n+1}=p^{k-a},m-2^{n+1}=p^a\implies 2^{n+2}=p^a(p^{k-2a}-1)$$
Since $\gcd(2,p)=1$, we get $a=0$ to have
$$ p^{k}-2^{n+2}=1$$

If $2^{n+2}+1$ is prime, then $k=1$.

If $2^{n+2}+1$ is not prime, then $k\ge 2$. By [Catalan's conjecture (or Mihăilescu's theorem)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture), there is no solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @mathlove!  I hope you do not mind my spelling edits.  =)

Comment: @Jose Arnaldo Bebita-Dris : Thank you for the edit :)

Comment: Gladly accepting your answer now, @mathlove!  =)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case $z = 4$.

We obtain
$$m^2 - p^k = 16$$
$$m^2 - 16 = p^k$$
$$(m + 4)(m - 4) = p^k$$
$$p^{k-x} = m + 4$$
$$p^x     = m - 4$$
$$p^{k-x} - p^x = 8$$

$$p^x (p^{k-2x} - 1) = 8$$

Since $p$ is prime and $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then we have $\gcd(p^x, 8) = 1$, which implies that
$$p^{k-2x} - 1 = 8$$
$$p^{k-2x} = 9$$
$$p = 3 \land k - 2x = 2$$
contradicting $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Therefore, under the given constraints, the Diophantine equation
$$m^2 - p^k = 16$$
does not have any solutions.

Comment: Consider $z=16$.  $m^2 - p^k = 64$, $m^2 - 64 = p^k$, $(m + 8)(m - 8) = p^k$.
$$p^{k-x} = m + 8$$
$$p^x     = m - 8$$

$$p^x (p^{k-2x} - 1) = 16$$

$$\gcd(p^x, 16) = 1 \implies p^{k-2x} - 1 = 16 \implies p^{k-2x} = 17 \implies p = 17 \land k - 2x = 1 \implies x = 0 \implies k = 1 \implies m = 9.$$