# Is it possible to derive $m < p^k$ from the Diophantine equation $m^2 - p^k = 4z$ unconditionally, when it is solvable?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations, divisor-sum

This question is an offshoot of this [earlier one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3515496).

Allow me to state my question in full:

> Is it possible to derive $m < p^k$ from the Diophantine equation $m^2 - p^k = 4z$ unconditionally, where $z \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p$ is a prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, when it is solvable?  (Note that I am only considering those $p$ and $m$ for which $\gcd(p,m)=1$.)

In the OP's [attempt](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3515496/28816) to solve the equation $m^2 - p^k = 4$, it is shown that
$$p=5, k=1, m=3,$$
from which we have
$$3 = m < p^k = 5^1 = 5.$$

Additionally, in a comment, the OP solves the equation $m^2 - p^k = 64$ and shows that
$$p=17, k=1, m=9,$$
from which we get
$$9 = m < p^k = {17}^1 = 17.$$

The [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3515567/28816) considers the equation
$$m^2 - p^k = 2^{2n+2}.$$
MSE user [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/78967) gave the solution
$$p=2^{n+2} + 1, k=1, m=2^{n+1} + 1,$$
provided $2^{n+2} + 1$ is prime.

Note that mathlove's solution gives
$$2^{n+1} + 1 = m < p^k = \bigg(2^{n+2} + 1\bigg)^{1} = 2^{n+2} + 1.$$

**MY OWN ATTEMPT**

I tried adding $p^k - m$ to both sides of
$$m^2 - p^k = 4z,$$
but that did not really get me anywhere.

**ADDED TO QUESTION ON FEB. 21, 2020 (10:20 PM MANILA TIME)**

(This was added in response to a comment from MSE user [Servaes](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/30382).)  I would like to specify that I am considering the divisibility constraint $\gcd(p,m)=1$ to hold.

Comment: I don't understand; simply plugging in $m=p^k$ yields
$$z=\frac{m^2-p^k}{4}=\frac{p^{2k}-p^k}{4}=p^k\frac{p^k-1}{4},$$
which is an integer as $p\equiv1\pmod{4}$. So the equation is solvable for every choice of $p$ and $k$ with $p\equiv k\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, and there always exists a solution $m$ with $m\geq p^k$.

Comment: @Servaes, thank you for your comment and attention.  As you can see, the examples for $z=1$ and $z=16$ clearly indicate that $m < p^k$ is possible.  Would you mind fleshing out your last comment as an actual answer (and include additional details, as needs be)?

Comment: @Servaes, my apologies, I forgot to specify the divisibility constraint $\gcd(p,m)=1$.  Adding this detail to the question now.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the question is. Which variables are given and which are to be solved for? And do you want to show that *there exist* solutions with $m<p$, or that *all* solutions have $m<p$?

Comment: The variable $z$ is given. We ought to solve for $p, k, m$. I actually would want to show that all solutions have $m < p^k$, if that is not too much to ask? =)

Comment: The latter is impossible; if $(p,k,m)$ is a solution for some $z_0$, then $(p,k,m+4p^k)$ is a solution for $z=z_0+2p^k(m+2p^{2k})$, where of course $\gcd(p,m+4p^k)=\gcd(p,m)=1$ and $m+4p^k>p^k$ if we take $m$ positive.

Comment: More simply put; for *any* odd $m$ you have $m^2-p^k=4z$ for some integer $z$, so in fact $m$ can be arbitrarily large compared to $p^k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the existence of solution to

$$m^2-p^k=4z$$

is not enough to say that $m<p^k$. Take as a counterexample $m=9$, $p=5$, $k=1$, and $z=19$. Then

$$9^2-5^1=81-5=76=4\cdot 19$$

Of course, there may be a solution to $z=19$ such that $m<p^k$, but it requires more work to prove that this would always be the case for all $z$ where a solution exists.