# On the inequality $m < p^k$ where $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

This question is an offshoot of this [earlier one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3515496) and this [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3555053) as well.

Let $n = p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p, m)=1$.  Descartes, Frenicle, and subsequently [Sorli](http://hdl.handle.net/10453/20034) conjectured that $k=1$ always holds.

[Dris](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html) proved that $p^k < m^2$ and conjectured that $p^k < m$. The first inequality, together with [Ochem and Rao's](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2012-81-279/S0025-5718-2012-02563-4/S0025-5718-2012-02563-4.pdf) lower bound for the magnitude of an odd perfect number that $p^k m^2 = n > {10}^{1500}$, implies that $m > {10}^{375}$.

Now, following the discussion in the hyperlinked questions, we have the (Diophantine) equation
$$m^2 - p^k = 4z.$$

We obtain
$$m^2 - 1 = p^k + (4z - 1).$$

The last equation is equivalent to
$$(m+1)(m-1) = p^k + (4z - 1)$$
which implies that
$${10}^{375} - 1 < m - 1 = \frac{p^k + (4z - 1)}{m + 1}$$
from which we obtain
$$({10}^{375} - 1)(m + 1) < p^k + (4z - 1).$$

The last inequality implies that
$$m < ({10}^{375} - 1)m < p^k + [(4z - 1) - ({10}^{375} - 1)] < p^k$$
provided that
$$m^2 - p^k = 4z < {10}^{375}< m.$$
But the inequality
$$m^2 - p^k < m$$
together with the inequality
$$m < p^k$$
will imply that
$$\frac{m^2}{2} < p^k,$$
contradicting [Dris](https://www.fq.math.ca/Abstracts/54-4/dris.pdf) and [Luca](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.1437v6.pdf)'s lower bound of $\sigma(m^2)/p^k > 5$.

**Added in response to a comment from MSE user [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/78967)**

Since
$$\sigma(p^k)\sigma(m^2)=\sigma(p^k m^2)=\sigma(n)=2n=2 p^k m^2,$$
$\sigma(m^2)/p^k > 5$ implies that $\sigma(p^k)/m^2 < 2/5$, from which it follows that 
$$p^k < \sigma(p^k) < \frac{2m^2}{5}.$$
As already noted above, this contradicts
$$\frac{m^2}{2} < p^k.$$

Here is my question:

> Does this proof argument conclusively show how to prove the Dris Conjecture that $p^k < m$?  If not, how can it be mended to produce a logically sound proof?

Comment: Can you add some explanations about how $\frac{m^2}{2} < p^k$ contradicts $\sigma(m^2)/p^k > 5$?

Comment: @mathlove:  Sure, hold on.  Doing so now.

Comment: Thanks. I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer.

> Does this proof argument conclusively show how to prove the Dris Conjecture that $p^k < m$?

No, it doesn't.

What you've done is as follows :

(1) Suppose that $m^2 - p^k  < {10}^{375}$.

(2) Then, $m^2 - p^k  \lt m$.

(3) Also, $m < p^k$.

(4) Finally, $\frac{m^2}{2} < p^k$ which is a contradiction.

In short, what you've got is

"Supposing that $m^2 - p^k  < {10}^{375}$ gives a contradiction."

Therefore, what you can say is $m^2 - p^k  \ge {10}^{375}$, not $p^k\lt m$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @mathlove!  I appreciate it.  =)